# How can I setText on Button array in Looping on Fragment?

Tags: android, loops

I want to setText on Button, with the text I get from json parse, and set it into Button Array. I wonder to set via looping. Can anyone help me?

```
for(int i = 0; i < jumlah_table; i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    final  String nama[] = new String[jumlah_table];
    nama[i] = object.getString("table_name");
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int j = 0;
            buttons[j].setText(nama[j]);
            j++;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should use AsyncTask and run this code in `onPostExecute` and the loop can be simplified too

Comment: I would initialize j outside your Runnable also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: initialize your array outside:

```
final  String nama[] = new String[jumlah_table];
```

Now in Asynch task `onPostExecute` use the following code;

```
  for (int i = 0; i < jumlah_table; i++) {
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    nama[i] = object.getString("table_name");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setId(i);
    final int id_ = btn.getId();
    btn.setText(nama[i]);
    linear.addView(btn, params);
}
```

where

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I guess this is what you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jumlah_table; i++) {
JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
final  String nama[] = new String[jumlah_table];
nama[i] = object.getString("table_name");
int j = i;
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        buttons[j].setText(nama[j]);
    }
});
```

}